# Margin not working (xml)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a weird problem. The margin is not working correctly as it should be. It's actually not working all, I dont see any changes when I edit the margin bottom or margin top.

I want the copyright to stick to the bottom and I want my button to have some space from the textview.

My question: how do I let the textview copyright stick to the bottom + how do I create some space between the button and textview?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#ffffff"
android:padding="20dp"
>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/titel1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="ACT-test"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tekst1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Text."
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    >
</TextView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Doe de ACT-test"  
android:background="@drawable/yellow" 
style="@style/ButtonText"    
android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >
</Button>  

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Bekijk je ACT-scores"  
android:background="@drawable/blue" 
style="@style/ButtonText"  >
</Button>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/copyright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Copyright 2002."
    android:textSize="10sp" 
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
</TextView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "margin is not working correctly as it should be" - how isn't it?

Comment: I edited the post with more information.

Comment: You need a `RelativeLayout` -- `LinearLayout` works as it's meant to. All your UI elements will be stacked vertically from top to bottom. Alternately, you could place `View` between the `Button` and the `TextView` with `height="fill_parent"`.

Comment: In an other project of mine I'm pretty sure I used margintop to seperate the textview with the button. Can you explain me why margintop isn't working now?

Comment: I can only tell you that there is no `margin_top` in the code you provided. It can't work if it's not there.

Comment: There is a param at button1, android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

Comment: It actually is working when I delete the  
style="@style/ButtonText"

Comment: Sorry, I was only looking at your copyright text, since that's what you asked about. Not sure why marginTop wouldn't work to separate the button from the top -- is it possible that your style overwrites the margins?

Comment: Oh look, crossed in transit. So check the style, probably has margins built in.

Comment: Yes thank you! Problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="ACT-test"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tekst1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Text."
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Doe de ACT-test" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bekijk je ACT-scores" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/copyright"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Copyright 2002."
        android:textSize="10sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: giving weight 1 makes your textview take entire remaining space
and by setting gravity you can mainitain position text inside textview
your textview is at bottom now you can add margins to your button

Answer (score -1):

You will need to set the copyright Textview to

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom
```

This should then allow you to set a margin on the bottom.

Which button, and which text view are you trying to put space between?

Comment: Textview tekst1 and Button button1.

It says the android:layout_alignParentBottom is an invalid param for linear layout? Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `layout_alignParentBottom` only works for Views inside a `RelativeLayout`, **not** in a `LinearLayout`.